# EJBs - problems running a simple tutorial example in Eclipse with JBOSS 7.1.1 server

Tags: eclipse, jakarta-ee, jboss, ejb

I just started to work on a tutorial example fr EJBs: http://eai-course.blogspot.com/2012/10/a-simple-enterprise-javabeans-31.html. It deploys the Ejb-project succesfully at the standalaone/deployments folder. When I try to run the Client project, it gives me no errors, but doesn't show me any output, it some how closes the connection. Here is the server log:

```
10:52:29,953 INFO  [org.jboss.modules] JBoss Modules version 1.1.1.GA
10:52:30,127 INFO  [org.jboss.msc] JBoss MSC version 1.0.2.GA
10:52:30,171 INFO  [org.jboss.as] JBAS015899: JBoss AS 7.1.1.Final "Brontes" starting
10:52:30,826 INFO  [org.xnio] XNIO Version 3.0.3.GA
10:52:30,826 INFO  [org.jboss.as.server] JBAS015888: Creating http management service using socket-binding (management-http)
10:52:30,835 INFO  [org.xnio.nio] XNIO NIO Implementation Version 3.0.3.GA
10:52:30,841 INFO  [org.jboss.remoting] JBoss Remoting version 3.2.3.GA
10:52:30,861 INFO  [org.jboss.as.logging] JBAS011502: Removing bootstrap log handlers
10:52:30,864 INFO  [org.jboss.as.configadmin] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 26) JBAS016200: Activating ConfigAdmin Subsystem
10:52:30,872 INFO  [org.jboss.as.security] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 44) JBAS013101: Activating Security Subsystem
10:52:30,875 INFO  [org.jboss.as.clustering.infinispan] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 31) JBAS010280: Activating Infinispan subsystem.
10:52:30,882 INFO  [org.jboss.as.naming] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 38) JBAS011800: Activating Naming Subsystem
10:52:30,885 INFO  [org.jboss.as.osgi] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 39) JBAS011940: Activating OSGi Subsystem
10:52:30,886 INFO  [org.jboss.as.webservices] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 48) JBAS015537: Activating WebServices Extension
10:52:30,891 INFO  [org.jboss.as.security] (MSC service thread 1-13) JBAS013100: Current PicketBox version=4.0.7.Final
10:52:30,933 INFO  [org.jboss.as.connector] (MSC service thread 1-16) JBAS010408: Starting JCA Subsystem (JBoss IronJacamar 1.0.9.Final)
10:52:30,944 INFO  [org.jboss.as.naming] (MSC service thread 1-3) JBAS011802: Starting Naming Service
10:52:30,948 INFO  [org.jboss.as.mail.extension] (MSC service thread 1-10) JBAS015400: Bound mail session [java:jboss/mail/Default]
10:52:30,964 INFO  [org.jboss.as.connector.subsystems.datasources] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 27) JBAS010403: Deploying JDBC-compliant driver class org.h2.Driver (version 1.3)
10:52:31,033 INFO  [org.jboss.ws.common.management.AbstractServerConfig] (MSC service thread 1-16) JBoss Web Services - Stack CXF Server 4.0.2.GA
10:52:31,055 INFO  [org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Protocol] (MSC service thread 1-11) Starting Coyote HTTP/1.1 on http-localhost-127.0.0.1-8080
10:52:31,257 INFO  [org.jboss.as.connector.subsystems.datasources] (MSC service thread 1-1) JBAS010400: Bound data source [java:jboss/datasources/ExampleDS]
10:52:31,271 INFO  [org.jboss.as.remoting] (MSC service thread 1-6) JBAS017100: Listening on localhost/127.0.0.1:4447
10:52:31,271 INFO  [org.jboss.as.remoting] (MSC service thread 1-8) JBAS017100: Listening on /127.0.0.1:9999
10:52:31,272 INFO  [org.jboss.as.server.deployment.scanner] (MSC service thread 1-2) JBAS015012: Started FileSystemDeploymentService for directory C:\JBOSS\jboss-as-7.1.1.Final\standalone\deployments
10:52:31,346 INFO  [org.jboss.as.server.deployment] (MSC service thread 1-8) JBAS015876: Starting deployment of "Ejb-Add.jar"
10:52:31,437 INFO  [org.jboss.as.ejb3.deployment.processors.EjbJndiBindingsDeploymentUnitProcessor] (MSC service thread 1-4) JNDI bindings for session bean named AddBean in deployment unit deployment "Ejb-Add.jar" are as follows:

    java:global/Ejb-Add/AddBean!ejbs.AddBeanRemote
    java:app/Ejb-Add/AddBean!ejbs.AddBeanRemote
    java:module/AddBean!ejbs.AddBeanRemote
    java:jboss/exported/Ejb-Add/AddBean!ejbs.AddBeanRemote
    java:global/Ejb-Add/AddBean
    java:app/Ejb-Add/AddBean
    java:module/AddBean

10:52:31,526 INFO  [org.jboss.as] (MSC service thread 1-11) JBAS015951: Admin console listening on http://127.0.0.1:9990
10:52:31,527 INFO  [org.jboss.as] (MSC service thread 1-11) JBAS015874: JBoss AS 7.1.1.Final "Brontes" started in 1797ms - Started 172 of 249 services (76 services are passive or on-demand)
10:52:31,670 INFO  [org.jboss.as.server] (DeploymentScanner-threads - 2) JBAS018559: Deployed "Ejb-Add.jar"
10:52:45,357 INFO  [org.jboss.as.naming] (Remoting "user-pc" task-4) JBAS011806: Channel end notification received, closing channel Channel ID 676e5052 (inbound) of Remoting connection 116a393d to /127.0.0.1:50941
```

The jndi.properties file is:

```
java.naming.factory.initial=org.jboss.naming.remote.client.InitialContextFactory
java.naming.provider.url=remote://localhost:4447
jboss.naming.client.ejb.context=true
#username
java.naming.security.principal=arba
#password
java.naming.security.credentials=kada
```

Comment: Did you create that user in application server?

Comment: I created an application user. In the question I added the jndi.properties file

Comment: Did you just try running it through `main` method?I don't see the article mentioning that you should deploy it

Comment: In the article stays: "Now, it's time to deploy. We will run the server on a console and export the .jar file...". After this step, the the result (Ejb-Add.jar) is shown in the deployment directory. Everything is working as it is in the article, except the result of the last step

Comment: instead of to throw  NamingException in the main method, try to catch it and print the stack trace. Maybe you are getting an exception and you don't see it. (also check the Eclipse Console view)

Comment: I made the change, but again it's the same output. Actually when I put in the first line of the main method simple printing expression (System.out.println("Test");), it doesn't show even the string "Test", it simply closes the connection

Comment: are you watching the correct Eclipse Console? Take in mind that your client code run in a different JVM than your server, each process has his own [Console](http://help.eclipse.org/juno/index.jsp?topic=%2Forg.eclipse.jdt.doc.user%2Freference%2Fviews%2Fconsole%2Fref-console_view.htm)

Comment: You are right, I was not watching the correct Eclipse console. I checked the error in the other console, and the output is: Cannot register namejavax.naming.NameNotFoundException: EJB-Add/AddBean!ejbs.AddBeanRemote -- service jboss.naming.context.java.jboss.exported.EJB-Add."AddBean!ejbs.AddBeanRemote"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem solved adding a jboss-ejb-client.properties file to the client application with the following code:

```
remote.connectionprovider.create.options.org.xnio.Options.SSL_ENABLED=false
remote.connections=default
remote.connection.default.host=localhost
remote.connection.default.port = 4447
remote.connection.default.connect.options.org.xnio.Options.SASL_POLICY_NOANONYMOUS=false
```

Answer (score 0):

I made the tutorial and it works fine. 
The problem is that the JNDI entry name that you have used to lookup the EJB is wrong.

The exception says:

Cannot register namejavax.naming.NameNotFoundException:**EJB**-Add/AddBean!ejbs.AddBeanRemote

and it is true, because 
according to your the server log the correct binding name is **Ejb**-Add/AddBean!ejbs.AddBeanRemote.

Remember that Java is case sensitive.